# Troubleshooting python code (data scraping)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm new to python and data scraping, so I'm trying to learn as I go.  I don't understand why the line "    df = pd.read_html(url)[1]" doesn't work in the FOR loop, but it works no problem outside of the for loop.  any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
team_abbrev = ['crd','atl','rav','buf']
year = 2020
list_of_dataframes = []

for team in team_abbrev:
    url = "pro-football-reference.com/teams/" + team + "/" + str(year) + ".htm" 
    print(url)   
    df = pd.read_html(url)[1]
```

---

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\teams.py", line 12, in <module>
    df = pd.read_html(url)
  File "C:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-
packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 
1085, in read_html      
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 
913, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 
893, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 
213, in parse_tables    
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\14074\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 543, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have missed https in the url.
Changing line 8 from

```
url = "pro-football-reference.com/teams/" + team + "/" + str(year) + ".htm"
```

to

```
url = "https://pro-football-reference.com/teams/" + team + "/" + str(year) + ".htm"
```

works

Comment: This worked. Thanks.  I don't see a close link, therefore, if you want to close this you can or show me how to close it..

Comment: Thank you, yes I got the answer to my questions.  I tried upvoting, but it say's I cannot vote for my question :(